# How to override a function that is part of a category's original class?

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism, overriding, objective-c-category, class-hierarchy

for example let's say i have a class car with the following .h:

**Car.h**

```
@interface Car : Automobile

@property Engine * V6;

-(void)igniteEngine:(int) key;

-(void)StopEngine;

@end
```

and now I have a category Car(Test) with the .m file

**Car(Test).m**

```
@implementation Car(Test){
    Oil * testingOil;
}

...

@end
```

and i want to override a function in the following way

```
-(void)igniteEngine:(int) key //inside test
{
    [self applyTestingOil];
    [(reference to original class) igniteEngine:key];
}
```

how would I go by doing this?
if there is a different way of approaching this problem that would also be helpful

Comment: 1) You can't add ivars to a category. 2) It's undefined behavior when a category overrides a method in the original class and there is no way to call the original, overridden method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding a method in a category is not an option, as the behavior at runtime will be undefined: you have no way to know which of the base class or category implementation will be executed.

See [Avoid Category Method Name Clashes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4).

If possible, the simplest way to do this is to subclass the base class, and override the method there.

Is subclassing is not an option, you can use [method swizzling](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/). This will exchange the method implementation with your own at runtime.
But as Mattt put it: "Swizzling is widely considered a voodoo technique", so I'd avoid it if I could.

If you think swizzling could solve your problem, and you're ready to "take the risk", take a look at [JRSwizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle), which will handle most of the boilerplate for you.

Considering your ivar `Oil * testingOil;`, subclassing is again the only simple option. As rmaddy said in the comments, categories does not allow you to add ivars to the class. You'll need to use [Associated Objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) for this. And well... it's not pretty.

Comment: thank you, Im going to subClass to keep things simple